# Using a UIActivityIndicatorView for Login process but as I'm using a thread I can't stop it

Tags: ios, multithreading, swift, uiactivityindicatorview

I'm using a `UIActivityIndicatorView` to show the user that something is going on while I validate the login details. the code below shows what I'm doing:

```
func confirmLogin(sender: UIButton) {
    ViewController.gVariables.gUser = userNameText.text
    ViewController.gVariables.gPwd = passwordText.text
    ViewController.gVariables.gLoggedIn = ""
    indicatorView.startAnimating()
    passwordText.text = ""

    GetRemoteData.getValidationFromServer( { (svrData) -> Void in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.indicatorView.stopAnimating()
            self.indicatorView.hidden = true
            MenuViewController.processLogin()
        }
    })
}
```

The user name and password are passed to the `getValidationFromServer` method in my `GetRemoteData` class which handles a lot of other web service activity. I set my indicator to start animating before calling the method but the following code should stop the indicator but it makes no difference as it is on another thread

What can I do to turn my indicator off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The completion block of `getValidationFromServer` is dispatching the stopping of the activity indicator view back to the main queue. That is the correct way to do it. Your indicator view should be stopping when the code dispatched back to the main queue runs.

If the indicator view isn't stopping, there are only a few logical reasons why that might be happening:

1. You might have some other code elsewhere that is starting the `indicatorView` again (e.g. in `processLogin`).
2. You might have something that is blocking the main thread, preventing this code that was dispatched to the main thread from running.
3. Perhaps your completion block isn't getting called at all.

I would suggest putting a breakpoint or log message where you call `stopAnimating` and see if you're getting to that point at all. From there, you can diagnose the source of the problem. But the code provided in the question is not the source of the problem.